# How to change the style of a div based on the current Domain

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have code that appears on two sites, lets call them www.siteone.com and www.sitetwo.com

I'd like to hide a div but only if the user is on sitetwo.

I have limited access to the html but i can insert code before and after the div i want hidden, including adding other divs and js. jquery is available also.

my thought is something like this:

code inserted before:

```
    <script>    
        some js that changes the visibility of a div id 'hiddenontwo'
        if domain = www.sitetwo.com then set visibility of id=hiddenontwo to hidden
    </script>
<div id=hiddenontwo> <!-- open a a wrapper div as i can't set an id on the actual div -->
```

Code inserted after:

```
</div> <!-- Closing the wrapper-->
```

Questions:
is this possible?

as my js knowledge is zero, could someone be kind enough to show how it might be done?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Yes its possible. What have you tried?

Comment: Did you take a look at `location`? it has what you want.

Comment: You can add (i.e. with PHP) CSS class to body tag depending on current domain and you can use it to style (with CSS of course) different elements differently depending on that body class. More elegant solution - you don't need JS ifs everywhere on your page.

Comment: At the moment I've not tried anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could write something like that

```
(function(){
  var divToHide = document.querySelector('#hiddenontwo');
  if(location.host === "www.sitetwo.com") {
     divToHide.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
})();
```

Comment: HA ha! This did it, but I had to put the script after the div or it failed. To stop it popping up then disappearing I'll set the wrapper div to hidden and then set it to visible on siteone.com . Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

```js
if ( window.location.host !== "stackoverflow.com"
    && window.location.host !== "stacksnippets.net") {
  $("#divOnlyVisibleForStackOverflow").hide();
} else {
  $("#divNOTOnlyVisibleForStackOverflow").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divOnlyVisibleForStackOverflow"> DIV 1 </div>
<div id="visibleDiv"> DIV 2 </div>
<div id="divNOTOnlyVisibleForStackOverflow"> DIV 3 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    var domain = window.location.hostname;
    if(domain == 'www.siteone.com'){
        //do something
    }else{
        //do something
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I would check for non-www domain as well.

Comment: Well, i just gave an example. variable domain will contain whatever will be the url.